# How come the deterministic part of Wold decomposition does not violate stationarity?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, stochastic-processes, moving-average, deterministic

[Wold's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem) states that every covariance-stationary time series $\{Y_t\}$ can be written as the sum of two time series, one deterministic and one stochastic:
$$
Y_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\varepsilon_{t-j}+\eta_t
$$
where, among other things, $\{\eta_t\}$ is a deterministic time series, such as one represented by a sine wave.

I am puzzled by the inclusion of a time-varying deterministic part. Does it not violate the definition of stationarity? Since the expected values of $\varepsilon$s are all zero, $\eta_t$ gives the expected value of $Y_t$. If $\eta_t$ varies over time (such as a sine wave does), the expected value of $Y_t$ varies over time, thus violating stationarity. What am I missing?

*Update:* A [follow-up question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636434).

Comment: Richard, I am leaving a comment for I have not touched the topic for quite some time. But doesn't deterministic mean perfectly predictable? Mainly the term is not a time trend and that means it shouldn't violate the stationarity assumption.

Comment: @User1865345, if $\mathbb{E}(X_t)\neq\mathbb{E}(X_s)$ for some $s\neq t$, that looks like nonstationarity to me. By definition, $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_s)$ for all $s,t$ if the process $\{X_t\}$ is stationary.

Comment: Check this [note](https://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/lchrist/finc520/wold.pdf). Note how the concerned term is constructed.

Comment: @User1865345, thank you, this looks very relevant! And a bit challenging – no bedtime reading...

Answer (score 0):

The component $\eta_t$ is not "*a*" "deterministic" time series. It will be a time series such that it will be covariance-stationary (at least) itself.

Here the terminology "deterministic" (a terminology issue, once more), should better be "**conditionally deterministic**", because what it aims to convey is that $\eta_t$ is *perfectly predictable given the past values of the whole process*. It does *not* mean "deterministic" as in "a deterministic rule/function to generate it".

While a covariance stationary process could conceivably be broken into two non-stationary ones, where together the one would "cancel out" the non-stationarity of the other, it could not be decomposed into one stationary and one non-stationary component.

Comment: Thank you. So $\mathbb{E}(\eta_t)$ is constant over time, right? I am still trying to get a better feeling of this "deterministic" term. I wish it were as simple as in my follow up question; is it perhaps?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes. As is the variance. The use of the term deterministic is unfortunate here.

Comment: @RichardHardy I posted also an answer to the follow-up question.